# Check if lowercase in SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS-access, and need to write a select query to find all rows where the cell value contains lowercase characters.

i.e. aa, aA or Aa but not AA

Can this be done?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209674

Comment: asc() works well, thanks. But it does involve checking each character individually, which could be tricky if cell contains a lot of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304258

```
Lower:StrComp(LCase([Field1]), [Field1],0)
Criteria: <>0
```

or as filter

```
WHERE StrComp(LCase([Field1]), [Field1],0)
```

Comment: Don't forget to put in some criteria so you're not comparing things that can't possible match. That is, if comparing two fields, you want to limit to the ones that match case insensitively first, and then use StrComp() on the remaining rows.